# What can we do during 9-hour layover in Dubai?

Tags: transit, layovers, dubai, tours

We will be arriving in Dubai at 6 am in the morning and will have to wait until 4 pm for the next flight. Are there any tours that we can do and how do we book them?

Comment: Are you flying Emirates? They have some special packages and arrangements for long stopovers in Dubai. We'd also need to know your nationality, to see what visa requirements apply.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you like to do! You probably want to go and visit the [Burj Khalifa](http://www.burjkhalifa.ae/en/index.aspx). The tallest tower in the world is a must see. If you don't want to go to the top, at least, check it out from the lake. There is a nice view.

Then, if you get there and you like shopping, check out the [Dubai Mall](https://thedubaimall.com/). If you want to see the old Dubai, then while going back to the airport, stop by Deira old city. Stroll in the small streets of the spice and gold souks.

If you prefer to refresh, check out [Ski Dubai](https://booking.skidxb.com/) at the Mall of Emirates. The Mall of Emirates is also a great place for shopping. There are some half days city tours. You'll easily find them on websites like this one on [Viator](https://www.viator.com/tours/Dubai/Dubai-City-Half-Day-Sightseeing-Tour/d828-2168DXB002).

On my [website](http://www.hotels-dubai.fr/que-faire-a-dubai/), I have also listed a lot of additional activities available in Dubai. Listing these here as my website is in French :

- Family activities : Dubai Aquarium, Aquaventure Waterpark, Wild Wadi Waterpark, beach time, Dubai fountain
- Sport activities : Skydive Dubai, desert stroll
- Sightseeing : Dubai Mosquee, Heritage Village, Dubai museum